# How to run an old 4:3 game on widescreen monitor?

Tags: games, display-resolution, playonlinux

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I used playonlinux to install the GOG version of Fallout 2 and the game runs very good (only there are problems with the resolution which is why I am posting here). Although there is a very popular high-resolution patch for this game, I don't want to use it. I want to play the game fullscreen and in the original resolution. When I run the game (which is made only for 4:3 displays), it looks very bad on my 16:10 monitor. I thought that changing the resolution of my display would help. So I changed the resolution to 800x600 (4:3) as you can see in the picture:
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/4298/SrB5lD.png
But then, when I run the game it is totally unplayable as it looks like this (although I have specified to run it fullscreen in playonlinux! (and it really runs fullscreen in the 16:10 resolution)):
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/1049/2icPnQ.png
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens in 1024x768? (This resolution might be better debugged.)

Comment: That does exactly the same thing.

Comment: You can try with another desktop environment. But don't mix it with your current Ubuntu with Unity. Instead you can try with a live or better *persistent live* system booted from a USB pendrive. You can create such a system with *mkusb*, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and I suggest that you try *Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 LTS*. It is possible that one of those desktop environments will work correctly in full screen mode with '4x3'.